# Assigning a value to a variable in a loop using Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm learning Matlab and I'm writing a code to find a specific value according to a condition using 'if'. The value can be easily found, but I want to know this value is created by which elements of array A and B. Unfortunately, I can not use this code. I would really appreciate your attention.

```
A=[2,7,1,3,10];
B=[2,7,1,3,10];
c=1;
k=0;
f=0;
L=length (A);
for m=1:L-1
  for n=m:L
     if(A(m)./B(n)> 0.09 && A(m)./B(n)<c)
        c=A(m)./B(n);
        k=A(m);
        f=B(n);
        end
     end
 end

fprintf('the c value is %0.5f',c)
fprintf('the A(m) value is %0.5f',k)
fprintf('the B(n) value is %0.5f',f)
the c value is 0.10000
```

Comment: Why don't you create 2 more variables to store the values of m, n in?

Answer (score 0):

just keep the position as k and f and refer to that

```
for m=1:L-1
  for n=m:L
     if(A(m)./B(n)> 0.09 && A(m)./B(n)<c)
        c=A(m)./B(n);
        k=m; %keeping the position
        f=n; %keeping the position
        end
     end
 end

if (f==0 || k==0) %if f or k is zero
    fprintf('No solution found\n')    
else
    fprintf('the c value is %0.5f \n',c)
    fprintf('the A(m) value is %0.5f at position %i  \n',A(k),k)
    fprintf('the B(n) value is %0.5f at position %i  \n',A(f),f)
end
```

Comment: You do not need the `./` for scalar division, use `/` instead.

Comment: I've tried it but there is an error : "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Comment: that would happen if there is no solution for the if case: k and f stay 0. I edited the answer so that there wont be an error